# How does one perform amplitude encoding using only unitary gates?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, encoding

How does one perform amplitude encoding using only unitary gates ?

Could you show me a concrete example ?

Answer (score 7):

In amplitude encoding, we encode data into the amplitudes of a quantum state. So, dataset is represented as a normalized classical $2^n$-dimensional vector, which can be thought of as a quantum state of $n$ qubits. Then, we create the quantum circuit that prepares this state.

As an example, assume that your dataset contains two points:

$$D = \{(1, 3), (0, 2)\}$$
We write it as a vector
$$V = [1, 3, 0, 2]$$
Then we normalize it
$$V' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}[1, 3, 0, 2]$$
This is a two-qubit quantum state which can be written as:
$$|V\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{14}}(|00\rangle + 3|01\rangle + 2|11\rangle)$$
So, we can embed it as follows:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
import numpy as np

state = (1 / np.sqrt(14)) * np.array([1, 3, 0, 2])
num_qubits = 2
circ = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
circ.prepare_state(state, [0, 1])
```

And to draw the circuit:

```
circ.decompose(reps = 4).draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! Can you explain what decompose does exactly ? How did you choose reps=4 ?

Comment: If your circuit contains blocks that is composed of sub-blocks or basis gates, `decompose`  expands these blocks. It does this one level only (shallow decompose). To repeat this operation,  set `reps` to the number of times the circuit should be decomposed. I chose $4$ by trail and error.

Answer (score 2):

The prepare_state method is not a standard method in Qiskit anymore, and it has been removed in recent versions.

To prepare an initial quantum state in Qiskit, you can use the initialize method, which takes a state vector as an input and prepares the qubits in the circuit according to that state vector.

Here is above example using the initialize method in Qiskit:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

import numpy as np

state = (1 / np.sqrt(14)) * np.array([1, 3, 0, 2])

num_qubits = 2

circ = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)

circ.initialize(state, [0, 1])
```